# Вызов функции из Oracle используя Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Приветствую!
Пишу REST сервисы. На Oracle БД есть функция, которая возвращает объект типа `EXP_TYPE`, определённого там же на БД:

```
 function GET_EXP_TYPE(pID in EXP_TYPE.ID%TYPE) return PKG_TYP.EXP_TYPE pipelined;
```

Моя задача просто вызвать эту функцию на нативном **SQL**, без использования Criteria API.

Общая идея понятна, но пока не удалось составить внятный список последовательности действий типа (очень примерно):

1. `Query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("TO CALL PROCEDURE", aResultClass);`
2. `Прописать result-set-mapping`
3. `Прописать приведение STRUCT к тому что мне нужно`

К тому же, не могу это нормально систематизировать. Поможете примером?
Либо кодом.

---

Слушайте, задаю уже второй вопрос такого рода и ни ответа ни комментария. Неужели никто ничего не знает?

---

JPA: Hibernate 5.0.10

IDE: JBoss Dev Studio

Comment: гибернейт - уже не нативный sql

Comment: @SeniorPomidor А Hibernate можно использовать в виде JPA провайдера, например так и писать: `entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT * FROM ...", aResultClass);`

Comment: Посмотрите сюда https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.html
Вам в помощь.

Comment: @GVArt Оставьте, пожалуйста, это в виде ответа и я приму его. Спасибо за Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать **hibernate** - Native SQL

Примеp:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM tableName");
```

Подробнее тут:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Answer (score 1):

Для вызова нативных заросов как раз есть такой метод: **EntityManager.createNativeQuery(String sql)**

а функцию можно подставить в селект 
**select your_function() from dual**

Согласно документации так же можно вызвать конкретную функцию.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#sp_query

Например:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectAllEmployments
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
st_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 OPEN st_cursor FOR
 SELECT EMPLOYEE,EMPLOYER,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,REGIONCODE,EID,VALUE,CURRENCY
   FROM EMPLOYMENT;

 RETURN  st_cursor;
END;
```

Результаты выполнения проецируются в свойства:

```
<sql-query name="selectAllEmployees_SP" callable="true">
<return alias="emp" class="Employment">
    <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
    <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
    <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
    <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
    <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
    <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
    <return-property name="salary">
        <return-column name="VALUE"/>
        <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
    </return-property>
</return>
{ ? = call selectAllEmployments() }
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, что в Hibernate ни в зуб ногой, знаю только Oracle. Если у вас есть `pipelined` функция и надо получить из нее данные "как из простого SQL", то надо всего лишь завернуть ее во view (на стороне оракла, естественно):

```
create or replace view my_view as 
select * 
from table(my_pipelined_function());
```

Дальше у вас будет в распоряжении обычное view, для внешнего наблюдателя абсолютно ничем не отличающееся от простой таблицы. И запросы к нему можно делать какие угодно.